# how to release the memory for a structure, pointer for each iteration of loop

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, struct

I have a structure

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned ccc;
  unsigned ddd;
  unsigned aaa;
  unsigned bbb;
  string ddd;

} objinfo;
```

which has be involved in the following places in my code:

```
objinfo obj_tmp
multimap<string, objinfo> obj_map;
multimap<string, objininfo>::iterator it;
std::pair<multimap<string, objinfo>::iterator, multimap<string,objinfo>::iterator> Krange;
```

each loop i will need to throw the old objinfo, obj_map and replace a new object information.
I can do obj_map.clear() to clean the map.

What else I should do to release the memory related to the structure, pointer and map for the old objects
after each loop?

Comment: that really depends on how your allocating memory for your structures.  Your structs could very well be on the stack, and thus not need manual memory management

Comment: Just use automatic object and memory management is done for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! My understanding is if i declare object struct as objinfo obj_tmp it is on stack. but if I use "new" then I should pair it with "delete" (then it is on heap), right? Then how about the pointers? its memory also be released after each loop (assume my declaration all inside the loop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [`multimap::clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/clear/) it will call the destructor of each element in the multimap. So as long as your elements aren't pointers, your objects will be destroyed and their memory will be freed. If you do have pointers as your elements in the multimap, you will need to call `delete` on each item before you call `multimap::clear()`. (Assuming you are the owner of the object).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've shared, it looks like all you need to do is let the objects go out of scope. Their destructors will run automatically and clean everything up for you. So, basically, you don't have to do anything. :-)

I say this because I see no manual creation of objects that need corresponding manual deletion (no `new` or `malloc`, for example).